# Fail to compile ternary expression in React component render

Tags: reactjs

I've noticed that my ternary expressions are breaking maybe 30-40% of the time when writing React components.  I'm not sure if there's a rule that they can't go into some particular place or what is going on, as the syntax looks valid to me.  The error message either isn't helpful or I'm just missing something glaringly obvious.

**Error**
[image: Error]
**The Component**

```
class AuthContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const {  errorMessage, handleLogin, handleLogout, isAuthenticated } = this.props
    return (
      { isAuthenticated
        ? <Logout onLogoutClick={() => handleLogout()} />
        : <Login
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            onLoginClick={(e) => handleLogin(e)}
          />
      }
    )
  }
}
```

`isAuthenticated` is a bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `{ ... }` in that scenario because you're not inside a JSX expression.

```
class AuthContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const {  errorMessage, handleLogin, handleLogout, isAuthenticated } = this.props
    return (
      isAuthenticated
        ? <Logout onLogoutClick={() => handleLogout()} />
        : <Login
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            onLoginClick={(e) => handleLogin(e)}
          />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: ah. that'd explain why sometimes it works and sometimes it breaks like this. I need to pay more attention to the context. Removing the `{` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens a lot due to the confusion of JSX and JS. This is how I go. I always put my logic outside the return. Try something like this:

```
class AuthContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const {  errorMessage, handleLogin, handleLogout, isAuthenticated } = this.props
    const Button = (isAuthenticated)?<Logout onLogoutClick={() => handleLogout()} />:<Login
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            onLoginClick={(e) => handleLogin(e)}
          />
    return (
      {Button}
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice I like this approach a lot. Keeps the return a lot cleaner